# Question about the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. I am trying to understand what the linear maps from $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{K}(\mathbb{K},V)$ look like. Given some $v \in V$, the map $f_{v}:\mathbb{K} \rightarrow V$ given by $f_v(k)=kv$ is linear and so $f_v \in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{K},V)$. I think that all the maps from $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathbb{K},V)$ look like this but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Did you mean to write $f_v(k)=kv$?  In any case, as you surmise, any such $f$ is entirely determined by $f(1)$.

Comment: Ohh yes, thank you! Edited.

Comment: No problem.  In that case, you have it right.  Just take $v=f(1)$ to establish the correspondence.

Comment: I see now, thanks!

Comment: On a side note, this space is isomorphic to $V$ : $\operatorname{Hom}_{K}(K, V) \cong V$ for any $K$-vector space $V$.

Comment: Ohh yeah. Using my notation, the isomorphism would send $f_v$ to $v$. Is that correct?

Comment: @billy192 That's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. Take any $g \in \mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb{K}, V)$ and set $v:=g(1)$. Now check that $f_v=g$.